# How to do intersection/union across all tables in schema?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a schema with multiple tables, all of which have a particular field, let's call it `foo`. They all have geometry `wkb_geometry` and unique key `ogc_fid`.

I need to create two new tables that would have intersections and unions of all features 'foo' equal to 'bar'.

I can do it for two tables specified explicitly:

```
-- intersection
create table intersection_results as
  select T1.foo, st_intersection(T1.wkb_geometry, T2.wkb_geometry) as geom
    from T1, T2
     where st_intersects(T1.wkb_geometry, T2.wkb_geometry) and T1.foo = 'Bar' ;

-- union
create table union_results as
  SELECT st_union(wkb_geometry) 
    FROM (
      SELECT wkb_geometry FROM T1 where foo = 'bar'
        UNION SELECT wkb_geometry FROM T2 where foo = 'bar'
          ) as moo ;
```

But what I am struggling with is to create a joined results table across all the tables  in my schema.

Comment: Intersection and union are very different tasks. The [Tour] requires one question per Question.

Comment: As I understand that you would work on many tables at the same time. I prefer to use (join)to  join the required tables and go further with your tasks

Comment: @User2009 If you have a chance to write it, how would you join the tables into one? That's essentially what I did, but I had to reimport the data with `ogr` appending new records to the existing table, thus not using the Postgres where I should have..

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you totally. If you already join them according to ogc.fid, why you need to add new records?

Comment: No, I didn't join them, just did it in a different (suboptimal) way. How would you join them?

Comment: @User2009 and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To intersect many tables and put the result in one table use the following: (you should modify it as your data and as you like)

```
CREATE TABLE new_intersect
AS
(select a.kb_geometry as A, b.kb_geometry as B from T1 a, T2 b where ST_Intersects
(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) and T1.foo = 'Bar'))
UNION
(select a.kb_geometry, b.kb_geometry from T3 a, T4 b where ST_Intersects
(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) and T3.foo = 'Bar');
```

And if you would to join them as we discussed, you can do the following by [Left Join](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-left-join.php):

```
Select *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.id=T2.id
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T1.id=T3.id
LEFT JOIN T4
ON T1.id=T4.id;   //and so on for other tables
```